# Error message in Xcode when working with watch complications

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

When executing

```
template.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: header)
```

in `ComplicationController`, I receive a whole number of similar error messages which I have not found a way to resolve so far:

```
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFilePlayerStatus is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoSerializer is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFilePlayerMessage is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoCacheSyncData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPComplicationData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPInterfaceSlider is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFilePlayerCurrentTime is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPColorWrapper is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoCacheAssets is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoObjectMessage is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoCacheAsset is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class WKAlertAction is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPInterfaceLabel is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFileQueuePlayerSetRate is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFilePlayerItem is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFileQueuePlayerSetItems is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPStockComplicationData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPStockListComplicationData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFilePlayerUpdateContainedIdentifier is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoSockPuppetMessage is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoSockPuppetObject is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPInterfaceImageView is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoCacheMessage is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPInterfaceSwitch is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPInterfaceButton is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPUtils is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPFont is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFilePlayerAsset is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPInterfaceMapView is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFilePlayerAssetUpdateMetaData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoSockPuppetPlist is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPCacheMessage is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPProtoAudioFileQueuePlayer is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPLogs is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPWeatherComplicationData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPCacheAsset is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPAssetCacheAssets is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[4499]: Class SPAssetCacheSyncData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework/SockPuppetGizmo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Here is the `ComplicationController` code for reference:

```
import ClockKit
import WatchConnectivity


class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource, WCSessionDelegate {

    var session:WCSession!
    var text:String = "watchdefault"
    var textOld:String = ""
    var header:String = "TestHeader"

    override init(){
        super.init()
        startSession()

    }

    // MARK: - Timeline Configuration

    func getSupportedTimeTravelDirectionsForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
        handler([.None])
    }

    func getTimelineStartDateForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (NSDate?) -> Void) {
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getTimelineEndDateForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (NSDate?) -> Void) {
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getPrivacyBehaviorForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior) -> Void) {
        handler(.ShowOnLockScreen)
    }

    // MARK: - Timeline Population

    func getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: ((CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void)) {
        // Call the handler with the current timeline entry

        if complication.family == .ModularLarge {

            //createData()

            let entry = self.createTimeLineEntry(text, date: NSDate())

            handler(entry)


        } else {


            handler(nil)
        }
    }


    func getTimelineEntriesForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, beforeDate date: NSDate, limit: Int, withHandler handler: (([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void)) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries prior to the given date
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getTimelineEntriesForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, afterDate date: NSDate, limit: Int, withHandler handler: (([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void)) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries after to the given date
        handler(nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Update Scheduling

    func getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler(handler: (NSDate?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the date when you would next like to be given the opportunity to update your complication content
        handler(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: (60 * 2)))
    }

    // MARK: - Placeholder Templates

    func getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
        template.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "header")
        template.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:"defaul text")


        handler(nil)
    }

    func requestedUpdateDidBegin() {
        print("Complication update is starting")


        createData()

        let server=CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()

        for comp in (server.activeComplications) {
            server.reloadTimelineForComplication(comp)
            print("Timeline has been reloaded!")

        }

    }



    func requestedUpdateBudgetExhausted() {
        print("Budget exhausted")
    }


    func createTimeLineEntry(bodyText: String, date:NSDate) -> CLKComplicationTimelineEntry {

        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
        template.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: header)
        template.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: text)

        let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date, complicationTemplate: template)
        return(entry)
    }

    func createData(){


        let applicationData = ["wake":"fromComplication"]


        session.sendMessage(applicationData, replyHandler: {(replyMessage: [String : AnyObject]) -> Void in
            // handle reply from iPhone app here

            //let answer:[String:AnyObject] = replyMessage
            self.text = replyMessage["text"] as! String
            print("complication received messagereply \(self.text)")

            }, errorHandler: {(error ) -> Void in
                // catch any errors here
                print("no reply message")


        })

        print("complication sent \(applicationData) to iOS")

    }

    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

        textOld = text
        text = userInfo["text"] as! String

        print("complication received userinfo \(text)")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        //if text != textOld {
            self.requestedUpdateDidBegin()
        //}
        }
    }




    private func startSession(){

        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self;
            session.activateSession()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Happening to me too. Doesn't seem to actually affect the code itself so I think it's a bug in the SDK or something.

Answer (score 0):

These are **not error messages**, these are just logs of **duplication warnings** found in watchOS SDKs that have classes with the same name.

Since these kind of issues are not something that a developer for a particular platform can and should modify, you can **safely ignore them**.